# Angular Karma Jasmine Date Comparision

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, date-comparison

Here, is the **SelectEndDate** Function where I'm comparing dates.

```
selectEndDate = () => {
    const currentDate = this.createDate();
    const endDate = this.addSurveyForm.value.endDate;
    const startDate = this.addSurveyForm.value.startDate;
    Eif (startDate === undefined || startDate === null || startDate === '') {
      this.addSurveyForm.patchValue({
        endDate: new FormControl({ value: ' ', disabled: true }, Validators.required)
      });
    } else {
      if (new Date(endDate) < new Date(currentDate)) {
        this.addSurveyForm.patchValue({
          endDate: ''
        });
      }
      if (new Date(endDate) < new Date(startDate)) {
        this.addSurveyForm.patchValue({
          endDate: ''
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to write test cases for this function. To check whether the start date is null if yes then I wrote this case

```
it('should call selectEndDate if startDate is null ', () => {
    const startDate = '';
    component.selectEndDate();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(startDate).toBe('');
  });
```

Now I'm not getting how can I cover else part, I'm not able to use less than operator for dates.
So please help me out.

Comment: You could use getTime method on date object of javascript for this comparison.
like `new Date().getTime() < startDate.getTime()`.
FYR - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Answer (score 0):

In this test

```
it('should call selectEndDate if startDate is null ', () => {
    const startDate = '';
    component.selectEndDate();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(startDate).toBe('');
  });
```

the two line

```
    component.selectEndDate();
    fixture.detectChanges();
```

Does not affect the test result. 
the `const startDate = '';` has nothing to do with `startDate` inside of `selectEndDate`. You need to change the value of form instead and test the value of the form as well.

```
it('should call selectEndDate if startDate is null ', () => {
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.addSurveyForm.patchValue({
      startDate: ''
    });

    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.selectEndDate();
    expect(component.addSurveyForm.value.endDate).toBe('');
  });
```

Also, it would be more reliable to subscribe to `component.addSurveyForm.controls.startDate.valueChanged` and update `endDate` inside that subscription. this way the `endDate`  would be updated whenever the `startDate`. Even if it happens outside of `selectEndDate` function